# Passing parameter into Task's Action delegate result in exception

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

Hi i'm trying to create a thumbnail using the TPL with the Expression's Behavior but i Hit the trying to access on a different thread exception at the File.OpenRead(uriSource) line. I'm trying to pass a UI Thread's parameter into a background task's Thread which causes the error I think... how can i solve this problem?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RenderThumb(UriSource)).ContinueWith((bs) =>
        {....}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationConext());

private BitmapSource RenderThumb(string uriSource)
    {

        Stream imageStream = File.OpenRead(uriSource);
        ...
        return bitmapSource;
    }
```

Comment: Our crystal balls seems to be malfunctioning today. Do you mind updating your question with the exact exception you got?

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is in accessing to UriSource as it's a dependency property. Try this:

```
string uriSource = UriSource;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RenderThumb(uriSource )).ContinueWith((bs) =>
        {....}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationConext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calling `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationConext()` from anywhere is not sufficient. Make sure that the calling thread is UI and already on a UI dispatcher when this code gets called i.e. Window_Load() / Button_Click() etc. event handlers are best place for calling this code.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RenderThumb(UriSource)).ContinueWith((bs) =>         {....}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationConext());
```

Now you may assume `ICommand.Execute()` should be ok, but they could cause an issue if the commands themselves were created on different thread like a background worker.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it solved the problem, not sure if this is the proper way of doing it...

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((s) => RenderThumb(s as String), UriSource).ContinueWith((bs) =>
        {...}, TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext());
```